Why does my exFAT external disk show errors on Windows and corrupt PDF files after formatting on macOS?
I partitioned an external disk as exFAT on my Mac using diskutil and the following commands:

diskutil list
diskutil unmountDisk force disk2
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 bs=1024 count=1024
diskutil partitionDisk disk2 GPT exFAT "Windows Partition" 0g

After partitioning, the output of diskutil list is:
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data HDD                     250.8 GB   disk2s2

After transferring a few files (JPG and PDF) to the disk and connecting it to a Windows machine, I received a message saying "There is a problem with this drive. Scan the drive now and fix it." If I ignore the message, the disk opens and I can access most files except some PDFs, which initially open fine on my Mac. However, once I try to open these PDFs on Windows, they become corrupt, and reconnecting the HDD back to my Mac does not allow me to open the files. In the file list, they appear greyed out. Moreover, the problem is still there if I select the option scan and fix the disk on Windows!
I followed the same process with another disk without any problems. For context, this disk used to be the internal HDD drive of my Mac, which I replaced, and I wanted to repurpose it as an external disk. Why do I get this "fix disk" error on Windows, and why do some files become inaccessible?
Edit1:
I used Disk Utility, selected "Show All Devices," and erased the top-level external physical disk. All files show up normally when I use the disk on Windows now, but the "fix disk" error still appears. If I press "fix," it says the disk is fixed, but the error reappears when I unplug and plug it back in.
Edit2:
The problem with some PDFs going bad after trying to use them on windows and then not being able to access them on Mac is still there. Maybe the HDD is problematic after all. Also, if I transfer a file into the HD from windows, it's not even visible on my Mac, like its not there.

What happens if you use Windows to partition and ExFAT format the drive?

@DavidAnderson it seems that things work but if I transfer files to the disk, then I can't open them on Windows, and on Mac I can't open them and for some files, I can't even view them. I went all the way to download testdik brew install testdisk, I run it but I can't figure out what's wrong with the drive

Is this a FusionDrive?

@X_841 this was the internal SSD of a MacBook Pro 2015 and it was a 256 GB OWC Aura Pro X2 256GB PCIe SSD model I think. I took it to a friend now who is a hardware engineer so I can't check but I don't think its a Fusion Drive
